# SQL return value 0 in case

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query

```
select  count(*) CountByGroup, IncomeGroup
from table1
cross apply (values(
            case
                when try_convert(numeric(20), hh.HouseholdIncome) between 0    and 4012 then 'Limit 2 - $4,012'
                when try_convert(numeric(20), hh.HouseholdIncome) between 4013 and 4956 then 'Limit 3 - $4,956'
                
            end)
            
        ) x(IncomeGroup)
```

and return

```
CountByGroup    IncomeGroup
17              Limit 2 - $4,012
```

Not sure how to get retun value 0 on group Limit 3 - $4,956 so it should look like if no value on group Limit 3 - $4,956

```
CountByGroup    IncomeGroup
17              Limit 2 - $4,012
0               Limit 3 - $4,956
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table and `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select count(*) as CountByGroup, v.IncomeGroup
from (values (0, 4012, 'Limit 2 - $4,012'),
             (4013, 4956, 'Limit 3 - $4,956')
     ) v(lo, hi, IncomeGroup) left join
     table1 t1
     on try_convert(numeric(20), t1.HouseholdIncome) between v.lo and v.hi
group by v.IncomeGroup
```